# Is this list commands meaning the same that other list of commands / --rebase flag

Tags: git, git-flow

Is this list of commands:

```sh
git checkout dev
git pull origin dev
git checkout 1234-bug-login
git rebase dev
git push -f origin 1234-bug-login
```

Doing the same what this does but shorter

```sh
git pull origin dev --rebase 
git push origin 1234-bug-login
```

Considering I always get my dev branch up to date starting to working on any kind of problem

Our company uses simplier github flow:

- we have only `dev` and `master`
- a developer is supposed to create a new branch starting to work on whatever
- when work is done a developer must pull `origin/dev` and then merge it with his local `dev` branch he has been working in
- when all conflicts are resolved the branch should be pushed to the remote repository
- merge request with `origin/dev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent, but only in minor details.

First of all, the second script lacks `git checkout`, so will pull-rebase `dev` into current branch (or rather: rebase current branch onto remote dev), whatever the current branch is, while the first script will ensure your are pulling remote dev to local dev.

Second difference, first script does `git pull` without --rebase. In case you don't have this option set in GIT it self, `git pull` will do a fetch&merge (remote dev to local dev). This step is completely missing in the second script.

Pretty different so far, so, I suppose you wanted to have

```
git checkout 1234-bug-login
```

as the first line of the second script. This will ensure both scripts try rebaseing the same branch.

Third difference, `-f` in the push command, pretty obvious. Considering that both scripts effectively do 'rebase 1234-bug-login' onto 'origin/dev', then either it is needed in both scripts, or neither.

Comment: You are right, I just want to comment few things about what you noticed. 
1. the second script lacks `git checkout` because I'm already supposed to be in the branch I have been working in so far. 2. I'm getting my local `dev` branch up to date when I start to work on any other thing and I will pull origin/dev even before making the branch itself 3. Yeah, `-f` is what shouldn't have both there scripts, it should be --force-with-lease for both. Thanks!

Comment: @DarkZ About "1." If so, get rid of it also in the first list to level the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Remarks :

- your local `dev` branch won't be updated in the operation. Might be inconvenient for diffs or other inspecting commands.
- you lack force on the last push, which would be necessary after a rebase, you'd need to add it :

  `git push origin +1234-bug-login`

Comment: OP already uses force in first script, so it'd be better to keep their syntax `-f`. Also, `-f` is not *always* necessary in this case, only if they pushed the 1234 earlier. Also, first script actually updates local dev, second does not, but I'm pretty sure that the second does update the tracking branch origin/dev, so diffs can work in some way or the other if they get them right

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I'm with you on the force part not being necessary, I tried to stay consistent with his existing process. ...which i did not about the syntax ^^ Point taken. But on the second subject, having `dev` and `origin/dev` not synchronized, albeit minor, is error-prone when you're switching from previous practice where you used to always have an up-to-date local `dev`.